# Have some serious doubts in zend framework 2 and rest api

Tags: rest, zend-framework2

I nearly find the way, how to implenment the REST Style in Zend Framework 2.

But my doubt is, the methods like get(), getList() is working fine, but the update() method id not calling and showing the following error in the html page.

HTML PAGE:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://128.199.233.137/api/v1/tes/74',
        data: {"gender":"1","country":"1"},
        type: 'PUT',
        success: function(result) {

        console.log(result);

            // Do something with the result
        }
    });


    OPTIONS http://233.102.233.137/api/v1/tes/74 jquery-2.1.3.js:8625 jQuery.ajaxTransport.sendjquery-2.1.3.js:8161 jQuery.extend.ajaxput.html:16 (anonymous function)jquery-2.1.3.js:4430 jQuery.event.dispatchjquery-2.1.3.js:4116 jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle
put.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://233.102.233.137/api/v1/tes/74. Invalid HTTP status code 405
```

MY controller is:

```
  <?php
namespace Tes\Controller;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController;
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;
use Zend\Http\Response;

class TesController extends AbstractRestfulController
{
    //getAction
    public function get($id) { 
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT');
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type");
        $resp = array("method" => "Get", "id" => $id);
        return new JsonModel($resp);
    }

    //updateAction
    public function update($id, $data) { 
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT');
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type"); 
        $resp = array("method" => "Update", "id" => $id, "data" => $data);
        return new JsonModel($resp);
    }

}
```

Comment: You are setting allowed methods to `GET, POST`. Try adding `PUT` here. `AbstractRestfullController` will return a 405 response anyway when you don't implement the update method, so setting the access-control headers manually is not needed imo.

Comment: Thanks, I have added a PUT now,  but still its not working and what is meant by implement the updae method?

Comment: Have a look at the `AbstractRestfulController` source code. The `update()` method is defined there and will return "method not allowed" response by default. What I mean by implementing is overriding the method in the child class `TesController`, this is what you have done already. Just try removing all the access-control headers and see if it's working.

Comment: I had a closer look and it seems jquery is doing a `OPTIONS` request by default, this is where the 405 error comes from. So you have to also implement `public function options()` in `TesController`

Comment: Thanks Bram, also when i try to check with the headers i sent, i found that i have sent method by "Get".

Comment: But what to make in options method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73642/discussion-between-mark-winkle-and-bram-gerritsen).